# Performing POST requests

Tags: python, http

I have some code that i have to convert from Javascript to Python.

In JS side, the code performs HTTP requests using `fetch`:

```
let resp = await fetch( url + 'get/token', { method: 'POST', mode: 'cors', body: fd });
let data = await resp.json();
return data.token;
```

How the `fetch()` command for javascript can be performed from Python? What is the equivalent command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `Flask` for this. So if you just want to perform a simple Post Request to a given URL just use the Pythons Request Library like so:

```py
import requests

url = 'someurl'
myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'} # if you want to send JSON Data

x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)

print(x.text)
```

EDIT:

As @OneCricketeer mentioned in his comment you could do this also with the `urllib` Package which is included in the Python 3.

```py
from urllib import request
from urllib.parse import urlencode


req = request.Request('your-url', method="POST")
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json') # you could set any header you want with that method
data = urlencode({"key":"value"})
data = data.encode()

response = request.urlopen(req, data=data)
content = response.read()
```

Comment: You don't have to install _any package_. `urllib` works too

Comment: Thank both of you guys... Have a great year!